# Get EURUSD Live Google Rate Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is there a way to get easily in python the EURUSD rate provided by google?

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=eur+usd&rlz=1C1CHBF_enFR918FR918&oq=eur+usd&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i20i263l2j0l2j69i60l3.1593j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

First download the forex library:

```
pip install forex-python
```

Then try this code.

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

c = CurrencyRates()

print(c.get_rate('USD', 'EUR'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=eur+usd&oq=eur+usd&ie=UTF-8&hl=en"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
print(
    "1 EUR is {} USD".format(soup.select_one("span[data-value]")["data-value"])
)
```

Prints:

```
1 EUR is 1.176 USD
```